# June is here. Who's ready for another Mario Marathon?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

As some of you may recall, last year Arqade took part in the annual [Mario Marathon!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/should-arqade-participate-in-mario-marathon)

Personally, I feel it was a *huge* success! It (hopefully) brought traffic to the site, and put us in the spotlight for a bit as #5 in the Top Ten list of contributors! Together, we raised over $1500 for Child's Play charities! I, for one, was completely blown away by the support of our users, and that of the SE Network, having chipped in $500 of their own. So, a big thank you to everyone who contributed last year!

Now, as expected, that time has come again! Mario Marathon 6 starts in just over **3 days**. I realize it's a little short notice to be posting this, but... I got distracted by work and video games. So... Yeah.

Our very own Ktash has set up his own referral link in an attempt to bring viewers to his own Arqade-community hosted charity event, the [Arqathon](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqathon.com)! He's even agreed to match what our users donate dollar for dollar! Or... someone will. Maybe not him. But he's promised a 1:1 match on all donations!

For those of you who don't want to support the Arqade-community's own charity stream, I'm going to post Arqade's very *own* [referral link!](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com)

**So, what do you say, Arqanoids, Arqanauts, Arqadians, and others? Can we get our name in the Top Ten again?**

<sup>Note: All donations are, of course, optional. However, if you do not use our referral link, we will not get credited with the donation!</sup>

Comment: we're officially known as Arqadians, we had a poll and everything

Comment: I blame Arqanoids for the downvotes.

Comment: We're Arqanadians, people.  Learn to love it.

Comment: I still fail to see the problem with 'Gamers'.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Compromise is for the weak.

Comment: Gamers game, we ask and answer questions too.

Comment: So we're ... Gasnswerers?

Comment: Sorry about dropping the ball on this. We had a discussion with plans to support this event in tandem, but then I had a family emergency in the middle of the week and the task didn't get picked up. Rather it fell into an abyssal molehole to never be seen again. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that ended a long time ago.