# For Charity. You Monsters

Tags: discussion, charity

It's that time of year again! [Mario Marathon](http://www.mariomarathon.com/) is back again this year. The stream starts this Friday (June 20th) and they are once again raising money for [Child's Play Charity](http://www.childsplaycharity.org/), a charity dedicated to improving the lives of children in hospitals around the world.

### The Deal

Just like [last year](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7306/15643), I will be matching donations to [**Mario Marathon made using this link**](http://mario14.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com). Any donations made through their site normally are harder to track, and so I won't be doing those explicitly.

That said, I'm changing it up this year. Some of you have said you support the idea, but would rather support a different cause. And this year, **I will be matching donations to the charity of your choice*.** I will be automatically matching all donations to Mario Marathon with the link above. If you have donated somewhere else, you need provide me with some sort of proof of donation (with the amount) and a place where I can donate. You don't need to share this with the world, you can send me an email (provided below).

**Donations must be made by June 23rd at 10pm PDT.** Any donations made after that will be matched at my discretion. I have an upper limit on amount I'm able to match (obviously), but we haven't gotten close to it at all in past years, so don't worry about that for now. If we start to get close to my limit, I'll let people know (and I'll be ecstatic).

* - Donations to other charities must have a place online where I can donate. And if they are not a registered charity with a government agency, I'll be using my best judgement to determine how reputable they are. Hopefully that won't be a problem, but if you are unsure, email me ahead of time and we can figure it out.

### Information

- [Mario Marathon Donation Link](http://mario14.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com)
- For donations to other charities

  - Email me
  - Please identify yourself and your charity in the subject or body
  - Include proof of donation amount
  - Also include location where I can donate (online only)
- Donations made before *10pm PDT on June 23rd* will be matched 1:1
- [Summer Games Done Quick](http://gamesdonequick.com/) is also running right now

### Tracker

Mario Marathon Donation Amount: [$230](http://mario14.mariomarathon.com/py/partner/arqade.com) raised and matched

Comment: Do the charities need to be US charities, or are you matching things internationally as well?

Comment: @AshleyNunn So long as I'm able to donate, and the charity is reputable, I will be matching wherever you want to donate. If you are unsure about something, you can always email me in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, any charity named "The Fund to Support @Yuuki's Gaming Addiction" is probably right out, huh?

Comment: @Yuuki If you can register with your government as a charity, I may consider it :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Event Over

Thank you everyone for participating. Mario Marathon is over $84,500 total raised for Child's Play, and we helped! Together we [donated $460](http://mario14.mariomarathon.com/py/partner/arqade.com) and helped a good cause. No one cashed in on the ability to donate to other charities, so that is our total for this go-around.