# It's dangerous to Charity alone

Tags: discussion, charity

**UPDATE:** [Matching is over](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10650/15643). Thanks to everyone who donated or promoted or just watched

[It's that time of year again!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9725/for-charity-you-monsters) Time for our (somewhat) annual charity-thingy. This year, Mario Marathon doesn't seem to be happening, at least not this month, however all is not lost. Instead, this year, ***[Zeldathon](http://zeldathon.net/)*** ([Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twxyDp1S6EY)) will be our featured charity this time around. The way we donate will be slightly different this year as well as they have no automated tracking (see below).

### Zeldathon

Zeldathon is a Zelda gaming marathon raising money for [Charity: Water](http://www.charitywater.org/). Zeldathon will start on June 19th and play through as many Zelda games as they raise money for (similar to how Mario Marathon does it). Charity: Water is an organization dedicated to bringing clean drinking water to people around the world. They have many different on-going projects and you can find out more about them on their website.

#### Other Causes

In addition, the same as last year, if you would prefer to donate to a different cause, you are more than welcome to. Feel free to donate to a registered/reputable charity or cause that allows me to donate online and I'd be happy to match. If you are unsure if I will match for a specific cause or charity, just shoot me an email at the address below and I'd be happy to discuss it with you.

### Quick Info

- Donate at [Zeldathon.net](http://zeldathon.net/)

  - For donations to Zeldathon, in the comment please mention the following: 
    *Donation is for matching by Ktash from Arqade*
- For donations to other charities

  - Email me
  - Please identify yourself and your charity in the subject or body
  - Include proof of donation amount (a screenshot or copy/paste is fine, and you can get rid of personal details. Just want the amount and charity really)
  - Also include location where I can donate (online only)
- Donations made before *8pm PDT on June 22nd* will be matched 1:1 up to $500

Comment: Should've gone with the FF5forFutures Four Job Fiesta. http://fourjobfiesta.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who donated. Unfortunately tracking did not work as well as I'd hoped, but I matched all those donations I knew about. If you did donate to either Zeldathon or a different cause, make sure to email me so that I know I got yours matched.