# It'sa Charity! Mario Charity

Tags: discussion, community-event, charity

[**Update: Donation matching has ended. See answer for the full breakdown.**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11752/15643)

---

The world has circled 'round the sun and we are once again at [that time of the year](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/its-dangerous-to-charity-alone). Charity time! And this year, Mario Marathon is back!!

## Donation Matching for Mario Marathon

[image: Watch the live Mario Marathon Stream]
[image: Donate Button for Mario Marathon with Affiliate Link]
[image: Link to the Mario Marathon FAQ for more information]

Donations that were made [using this link right here](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com) (or the button above) were automatically matched at the end of the matching period.

## Donation Matching for Other Charities

Like previous years, donations made to other charities or other causes are more than welcome! Feel free to donate to a registered/reputable charity or cause that allows me to donate online and I'd be happy to match. If the charity organization is not a registered charity with a government agency, I'll be using my best judgement to determine how reputable they are. If you are unsure if I will match for a specific cause or charity, just shoot me an email at the address below and I'd be happy to discuss it with you.

For me to match it, simply send me an email to the address below with the amount donated and the charity which you donated to. Proof of donation is great. You can exclude any personal information, but a screenshot of a confirmation page or email would be good to have.

## Timeframe

**Donation matching window has passed**

This year I started things a bit earlier to give people more time for donations to either MM or other charities. **Donations made between now and 9pm PDT on Sunday June 26th were matched**. Any donations made after that will be matched at my discretion. Also, like previous years, I do have an upper limit on the amount I'm able to match (obviously), but we haven't gotten close to it previously, so don't worry about that for now. If we start to get close to my limit, I'll let people know (and I'll be ecstatic).

## Information

- [Mario Marathon Donation Link](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com)
- For donations to other charities

  - Email me
  - Please identify yourself and your charity in the subject or body
  - Please try to include screenshot or something noting the donation amount
  - Also include location where I can donate (online only)
- Donations made before *9pm PDT on June 26th* were be matched 1:1

### Tracker

[Mario Marathon Donation Tracker](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/partner/arqade.com)

Comment: I also kicked us off this year with a little donation to get us onto the leaderboard :)

Comment: I have to say, it's absolutely fantastic that you do this every year.

Comment: Should we write "`http://arqade.com/`" to "If you would like your donation linked to a web site, what is the URL?"?

Comment: @ardaozkal As long as you donate from the link, you don't have to. You can write in any url you like there. You can if you want though :)

Comment: The title was/is intentional by the way :P

Comment: Yay! I completely dropped the ball on making a post about Mario Marathon! I didn't even know they were doing it this year. They skipped last year's and threw me off. D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Donations Matched

We had a big turnout this year! Thank you to everyone who donated, watched, shared, and helped for this drive. We did a great job to raise money for some amazing causes.

**This year, we raised a total of *$940.04!!*** In that, we donated to [Child's Play Charity](http://www.childsplaycharity.org/), [Direct Relief](https://www.directrelief.org/), and [the Polizzi Clinic](http://polizziclinic.org/). Causes like these rely on support from people like you donating and supporting them any way you can and people like you all are what make their work possible.

Thank you again to everyone!

Comment: 14 donors, $57.14 average, totaling $800.00, 2nd largest contributing site. This is, as it seems, counting only the Child's Play donations. (This does not mean you can't keep donating :)