# This isn't donating. It's charity, with style!

Tags: discussion, charity

Summer is back and I'm still here! Which [as usual](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/its-dangerous-to-charity-alone) means it's charity time!

## Automatic Donation Matching for Mario Marathon

[image: Watch the live Mario Marathon Stream]
[image: Donate Button for Mario Marathon with Affiliate Link]
[image: Link to the Mario Marathon FAQ for more information]

Donations made [using this link right here](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com) (or the button above) will be automatically matched at the end of the matching period.

## Donation Matching for Other Charities

Like previous years, donations made to other charities, marathons, or causes are more than welcome! Feel free to donate to a registered/reputable charity or cause that allows me to donate online and I'd be happy to match. If the charity organization is not a registered charity with a government agency, I'll be using my best judgement to determine how reputable they are. If you are unsure if I will match for a specific cause or charity, just shoot me an email at the address below and I'd be happy to discuss it with you.

For me to match it, simply send me an email to the address below with the amount donated and the charity which you donated to. Proof of donation is great. You can exclude any personal information, but a screenshot of a confirmation page or email would be good to have.

## Timeframe

**Donations made between now and 9pm PDT on Monday June 26th will be matched**. Any donations made after that will be matched at my discretion.

Also, like previous years, I do have an upper limit on the amount I'm able to match (obviously), but we haven't gotten close to it previously, so don't worry about that for now. If we start to get close to my limit, I'll let people know (and I'll be ecstatic).

## Information

- [Mario Marathon Donation Link](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/donate?rr=arqade.com)
- For donations to other charities

  - Email me
  - Please identify yourself and your charity in the subject or body
  - Please try to include screenshot or something noting the donation amount
  - Also include location where I can donate (online only)
- Donations made before *9pm PDT on June 26th* will be matched 1:1

### Tracker

[Mario Marathon Donation Tracker](http://www.mariomarathon.com/py/partner/arqade.com)

Comment: Looks like I broke my email over the weekend so if you sent me an email for this in the past few days you may need to resend it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Donations Matched

Thanks everyone for donating! We raised $178.40 this year. Great job everyone, you're all rockstars!