# Is SE doing anything for Mario Marathon this year?

Tags: discussion, charity

Two years ago, [SE did something for Mario Marathon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4845/15643). Last year, however, they opted not to (perfectly fine), but [I did a bit myself](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7306/15643). Likely I'm going to do something else this year because we didn't ever get [our own marathon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5731/15643) of the ground, and this is usually the time of year I do this sort of thing. Is SE (the company) going to participate in Mario Marathon (or SGDQ) this year at all? I.e. do I have some event or something I'll need to work with or around for my own thing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess this is a no and assume I can do my own thing without any issues.